# Creating overview map in ArcGIS Pro that refers to extents of map frames in other layouts

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I'm putting together a map book and would like an "overview" map which will show the extents of the maps that will follow it. I've looked at the Extent Indicators help page here:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/extent-indicators.htm

The help page only gives instructions on how to set up Extent Indicators that are referring to another map frame on the same layout.

Is there a way to refer to a map frame on a separate layout in the same project or any workarounds to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: I've done a lot with Map Series in ArcGIS Pro, including realeasing an eLearning course named [Making Maps and Map Series using ArcGIS Pro Layouts](https://www.udemy.com/course/making-maps-and-map-series-using-arcgis-pro-layouts/?referralCode=26DF74298F530DFCA6E9), but I'm not sure what type of index map you are trying to achieve.  Is it just a front page with an index map on it to include before your map series pages?  A picture of what you are after may help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @PolyGeo. I think I was asking the question in a somewhat backward way from the way more seasoned professionals think about these things. I found this video on producing a map series quite helpful: [ArcGIS Pro Map Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emlb7AXuM5o)

Comment: After watching that, if you still have a question to ask, can you use the [edit] button to revise it, please?