# Have a data-driven page that changes a layer query so only a single feature shows without the scale changing

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

What I am trying to do is create data-driven pages. I just haven't figured out how to do it to fit my needs. Or maybe I am not using the right terms to find what I need. A description of what I am trying to do follows.

I have a layout with two map frames. There is a small map that shows the full extent of the project area. The large map shows a closer view of the project so the audience can see more specific information. What I need is for the small map to identify the view of the large map in comparison to the whole project.

How I have been dealing with this. I set a bookmark at the view that I want for the big map. Then I create features based on that view (Draw squares around what I can see then give them an attribute that identifies them the same as the bookmark). I then set up the layout, so the map series is connected to the large map and I have quick access to the bookmarks. I then use the definition query on the feature layer in the small map to make sure the area defined is the same area that is being shown in the large map. This works, it's just very time-consuming. Especially when your project area can go through anywhere from 2-30 bookmarks.

How can I do this?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro has Map Series.  Only ArcMap has Data Driven Pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a data-series issue. Map extent indicators are easily used in any type of map. They are a property of data frames. You need to set map frame properties to link the overview and detail map frames and choose some symbology. You also have some choices about what to display, e.g., the whole data frame of the other map or its shape.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/extent-indicators.htm
[(ArcPro Help)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394511/creating-overview-map-in-arcgis-pro-that-refers-to-extents-of-map-frames-in-othe)

[Creating overview map in ArcGIS Pro that refers to extents of map frames in other layouts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394511/creating-overview-map-in-arcgis-pro-that-refers-to-extents-of-map-frames-in-othe)

There are what look to be some useful YouTube videos on this subject. I searched for "arcpro extent frame".